# Проблема при написании телеграм бота

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Пишу простого бота для телеграм в редакторе Web Storm. Запустив его в консоли,
я столкнулся с ошибкой:

`:error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 401 Unauthorized"}`

Как это исправить?

Comment: надо залогиниться

Comment: webSHtorm, забавно))

Answer (score 0):

```js
const TOKEN = 'токен'(;) = error
const TOKEN = 'токен' = started=)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]